# Looping through 2 String Lists

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, bukkit

I wanted to know how I could possibly loop through 2 string lists (array lists - Bukkit) to see if I can find the value I need. Currently I have:

```
for (String parent : fc.getConfigurationSection("generators").getKeys(false)) {
    for (String ls : fc.getStringList("generators." + parent)) {
    }
}
```

I then check if the value in 'ls' is equal to the value I am searching for. I see that using 2 `for` loops is bad practice which is one of the many reasons that I have been trying to find a way around.

My User File:

```
generators:
  262d327f-34e3-42be-87f5-235068661f30:
  - Spawn,0,60,-249,Common
```

Notice how they are player UUIDs followed by a location which is automatically saved, I wish to check if a value in the list is equal to the one I want before returning the parent (UUID) to find who that belongs to.

Hopefully I've made myself clear what I have been trying to approach.

Comment: Using 2 for loops is not necessarily bad practice, you see that put to good use regularly. If I understand correctly, you expect to find some specific value in the list returned by `getStringList()`? What I don’t understand is what behaviour do you observe instead? Also it seems you haven’t posted what’s inside the innermost `for` loop.

Comment: The code in the link looks sound to me, though I don’t know Bukkit (I believe `LocationConverts` must be yours, not a Bukkit class). It’s not that you’re converting the same `String` to a `Location` and back to the same String, is it? If you want more qualified help, I suggest you produce a minimal example that shows the unwanted behaviour, and also explain more precisely what’s unwanted about it. You may also want to try a debugger.

Comment: @OleV.V.Ya locationconverts is mine converting back and forwards, and i get a null error when calling that.

Comment: So the error is not even in the code you posted? How are we to help you? :-)

Comment: @OleV.V.I meant i get an error when calling the method i showed u :p

Comment: If you cannot your self tell from your stack trace what causes the error, you may want to post the stack trace here.

Comment: this code: `fc.getStringList("generators." + parent)`  return a list, i think you want to check that if this list contains a specified string or not! am i true?

Comment: could you tell us what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish? You have a certain location saved, and you want to check which player is there? Or you have a player and you want to check if that location is part of his saved location list? What are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: are the values returned from either method constant for a given jvm?